# Data binding in Design view

Tags: android, android-studio, android-databinding, code-completion, android-layout-editor

Does the Android Studio layout designer support data binding? Specifically, does the UI support code completion for data binding attributes like it does for resources. I have been manually adding data binding to the XML files to this point as I do not get any code completion in the designer.

If not natively, does anyone have experience with any plugins that accomplish this integration?

As nice as the layout designer has become (I started Android development when Eclipse was the standard...) It seems like a glaring omission if data binding is not supported.

Comment: This would be a great value add for Layout Editor. Perhaps the Android Studio team has not added this functionality if they are planning to move towards [Jetpack Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose) in future. ☝

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. I think if there are any other errors in the precompile of resources, you could have problems. In the picture below, I typed ".s" and the popup came up:
[image]

Comment: I see.  Sorry.  No, I don't think it does. From what I can see, for resources, it doesn't have code completion so much as dialogs with pickers, which would seem awkward to implement for code.